# Seperate Months of Different Years

Tags: powerbi

I have a column of data that I'm using as the Axis for a series of bar charts. Previously those dates ranged from January to Mid-December of 2018, but I'm updating the dashboard with new data that ranges to Jan 31st 2019. When I add the new data, those bar charts (which are grouped by month), seem to be combining the data of January 2018 with January 2019, where I need them to be separate.

Before adding new data: 
[image]

After adding new data:
[image]

Note that the counts go up for January because of the addition of January 2019, where as I want January 2019 to be its own Category distinct from January 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The little bifurcated arrow next to the other drill down buttons lets you group by multiple levels at once.